# How do I use Google_API to retrieve calendar events?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I'm attempting to user Google API's via PHP to retrieve calendar events.  My Environment

- Windows: 10
- PHP: 7.0
- Apache: 2.4
- Google API's loaded via command: composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"

I'm using the following as test code (test2.php):

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
This is a line of text in test2.php
<?php
require_once 'C:\PHP\vendor\autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();

// $credentialsJson should contain the path to the json file downloaded from the API site
$credentialsJson = 'C:\Apache24\htdocs\credentials.json';
$credentials = $client->loadServiceAccountJson(
   $credentialJson,
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// $calendarId should contain the calendar id found on the settings page of the calendar
$calendarId = '*****myCalendarID*****';

$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId);
echo $events;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I place the test2.php file in C:\Apache24\htdocs.
When I browse to: localhost/test2.php the browser displays:

```
This is a line of text in test2.php
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Client::loadServiceAccountJson() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test2.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test2.php on line 14
```

Why would this not find the method "loadServiceAccountJson"?
Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what tutorial you are following. this is the code i use.

[ServiceAccount.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place the file in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    return getServiceAccountClient();
}
/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed. 
 * array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Note: A service account is not you using this will be requesting data from the service accounts google calendar account.  if you want it to have access to your personal calendar your going to have to take the service account email address and share your calendar with it like you would any other user.

Comment: To answer your question, I'm using the tutorial from https://murze.be/how-to-setup-and-use-the-google-calendar-api

Comment: I used your example and I modified the following two lines:require_once 'C:\php\vendor\autoload.php'; and         $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly');  The code runs without error when I use the url:  localhost/test5.php

Comment: I would think you would add a calendar scope not a gmail scope

Comment: Thanks.  I used the scope line:         $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly');  No errors.  But how do I alter this so that I get a list of all the calendar's events?
How do I list out the calendar events using your tutorial?